# Trigger To update ConvertedContactId to custom objects when a lead is created

Tags: apex, trigger

I worked on one Apex class which will update the ConvertedContactId to Custom object when a lead is converted, my class is below but at sometimes I amgetting CPU run time error,can anyone help me out in this issue here if possible.

Class:

```
public class LeadAndRelatedTow {
//class to fetch the contact Id from lead and update to all related tow records when lead is converted
public static void leads(){
    set<Id> leadId = new set<Id>();
    List<Lead> allleads = new List<Lead>([select Id, Name, IsConverted,ConvertedContactId from Lead WHERE IsConverted = TRUE AND ConvertedContactId !=null]);
    for(Lead lead: allleads){
        leadId.add(lead.Id);
    }
    List<Lead> updatedleads = [select Id, ConvertedContactId,(select Id, Name, Lead__c, Contact__c from Related_TOWs__r) from Lead WHERE Id In: leadId];
    List<Related_TOW__c> alltows = new List<Related_TOW__c>();
    for(Lead leadstotow : updatedleads){
        for(Related_TOW__c tow: leadstotow.Related_TOWs__r){
            if(tow.Contact__c == null){
            tow.Contact__c = leadstotow.ConvertedContactId;
            }
            alltows.add(tow);
        }
    }
    update alltows;

}
public static void Marketingactivity(){
    set<Id> leadId = new set<Id>();
    List<Lead> allleads = new List<Lead>([select Id, Name, IsConverted,ConvertedContactId from Lead WHERE IsConverted = TRUE AND ConvertedContactId !=null]);
    for(Lead lead: allleads){
        leadId.add(lead.Id);
    }
    List<Lead> updatedleads1 = [select Id, ConvertedContactId,(select Id, Name, Lead__c, Contact__c from Marketing_Activities__r) from Lead WHERE Id In: leadId];
    List<Marketing_Activity__c> updatemarketingactivity = new List<Marketing_Activity__c>();
    for(Lead leadstotow : updatedleads1){
        for(Marketing_Activity__c marketing: leadstotow.Marketing_Activities__r){
            marketing.Contact__c = leadstotow.ConvertedContactId;
            updatemarketingactivity.add(marketing);
        }
    }
    update updatemarketingactivity;

}


 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Harish,

What is the injection point of you code? If this code is supposed to fire when a Lead gets converted, then we should be thinking about writing code which is called from the Lead Trigger. There are plenty of Trigger Frameworks out there, but in general, what you need to do is something like this:

```
public class LeadTriggerHandler {

    public void afterUpdate(List<Lead> newList, List<Lead> oldList) {
        Map<Id,Lead> newMap = new Map<Id,Lead>(newList);
        Map<Id,Lead> oldMap = new Map<Id,Lead>(oldList);
        List<Lead> convertedLeads = new List<Lead>();
        for (Lead lead : newList) {
            if (lead.IsConverted == true && oldMap.get(lead.id).IsConverted == false) {
                convertedLeads .add(lead);
            }
        }
        if (!convertedLeads.isEmpty()){
            LeadHelper.handleLeadConversion(convertedLeads);
        }
    }
}

public class LeadHelper {

    public static void handleLeadConversion(List<Lead> convertedLeads) {
        List<Marketing_Activity__c> activitiesToUpdate = new List<Marketing_Activity__c>();
        List<Related_TOW__c> towsToUpdate = new List<Related_TOW__c>();
        Map<Id,Lead> leadMap = new Map<Id,Lead>([SELECT Id, (SELECT Id from Marketing_Activities__r), (SELECT Id from Related_TOWs__r) FROM Lead WHERE Id IN : leads]);
        for (Lead lead : convertedLeads) {
            if (lead.ConvertedContactId != null) {
                for (Marketing_Activity__c ma : leadMap.get(lead.id).Marketing_Activities__r) {
                     activitiesToUpdate.add(new Marketing_Activity__c(Id = ma.Id, Contact__c = lead.ConvertedContactId));
                }
                for (Related_TOW__c tow : leadMap.get(lead.id).Related_TOWs__r) {
                     towsToUpdate.add(new Related_TOW__c(Id = tow.Id, Contact__c = lead.ConvertedContactId));
                }
            }
        }
        update towsToUpdate;
        update activitiesToUpdate;

    }
}
```

Comment: Mitch Spano, thanks a lot for helping me out in this issue but when I was passing triiger.new and trigger.old from trigger then I am getting error. my code `if(trigger.isAfter && trigger.isUpdate){
        LeadTriggerHandler.afterUpdate(trigger.new, trigger.old);
    }` I amgetting below error. "Non static method cannot be referenced from a static context: void LeadTriggerHandler.afterUpdate(List<Lead>, List<Lead>)"

Comment: Harish, that means that you must create an instance of LeadTriggerHandler or set the methods which I defined above as static. `LeadTriggerHandler handler = new LeadTriggerHandler(); handler.afterUpdate(trigger.new, trigger.old);`

Answer (score 0):

You have two queries when it really should be one.

1. You query all leads that meet a *certain condition* (isConverted = true and ConvertedContactId != null\
2. You then query all leads that are in that list of Ids returned by query #1

You can combine this into one by just using the WHERE conditions from #1 into query #2 and eliminate the for loop:

```
//query #1
List<Lead> allleads = new List<Lead>([select Id, Name, IsConverted,ConvertedContactId 
from Lead 
WHERE IsConverted = TRUE AND ConvertedContactId !=null]);

//for loop
for(Lead lead: allleads){
    leadId.add(lead.Id);
}

//query #2 
List<Lead> updatedleads = [select Id, ConvertedContactId,
(select Id, Name, Lead__c, Contact__c from Related_TOWs__r) 
from Lead 
WHERE Id In: leadId];
```

is the **same** as doing this

```
//single query
List<Lead> updatedleads = [select Id, ConvertedContactId,
(select Id, Name, Lead__c, Contact__c from Related_TOWs__r) 
from Lead 
WHERE IsConverted = TRUE AND ConvertedContactId !=null];
```

The benefit is that you eliminated another query and an unnecessary for loop. You can do this in the other area where you do the same thing `Marketingactivity` to save yourself another *for loop* and *query* and improve performance.